# TOSCA - How to verify second last row in tosca

Tags: tosca

I want to verify data from second last row of table.
I stored rowcount-2 in buffer, but not able to pass it to row number i.e $ or #

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the buffer to select the row number by using `${B[Row Number Buffer]}` in place of `<Row>`.